# Is this the correct way to install php-intl using docker?

Tags: php, docker

This never gets installed on my Github Actions even though I added `intl` in the end.

```
FROM composer:1.9.0

LABEL repository="https://github.com/ubient/laravel-vapor-action"
LABEL homepage="https://github.com/ubient/laravel-vapor-action"
LABEL maintainer="Claudio Dekker <claudio@ubient.net>"

# Install required extenstions for laravel
# https://laravel.com/docs/6.x#server-requirements
RUN apk add libxml2-dev libpng-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install bcmath xml tokenizer mbstring gd intl

# Install Vapor + Prestissimo (parallel/quicker composer install)
RUN set -xe && \
    composer global require hirak/prestissimo && \
    composer global require laravel/vapor-cli && \
    composer clear-cache

# Install Node.js (needed for Vapor's NPM Build)
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm

# Prepare out Entrypoint (used to run Vapor commands)
COPY vapor-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/vapor-entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/vapor-entrypoint"]
```

Comment: I had to enable main non-free contrib to install intl in one of my projects here is the repo for docker content. https://github.com/Madu-rosh/laravel-docker-setup. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I strictly need to amend what I have above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fixed it

```
# Install INTL
RUN apk add icu-dev 
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

https://github.com/aligajani/laravel-vapor-action/